# supporting Basic Auth and Form based Authenticaion in Grails

Tags: grails, spring-security

I need to support Basic Auth and Formbased authentication for a application using grails 1.3.6. Is it possible to do it using Spring Security ? Right now I do have form based authentication working for the application, what do I need to do more so that it support both ? Or is it not possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Spring Security can support basic auth along with form-based auth. To allow basic auth for specific URLs or patterns you can add the following configuration:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.useBasicAuth = true
grails.plugins.springsecurity.basic.realmName = "My App Name"
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/someController/someAction': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
    '/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-basicAuthenticationFilter,-basicExceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

Comment: You copy/paste from the docs very well ;)  http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/9%20Authentication.html#9.1%20Basic%20and%20Digest%20Authentication

Comment: Do I? I copied it out of my app, clearly once upon copied from the docs :)

Comment: quick question. Everything works user is getting authenticated but my RememberMeService code is not getting called when I do the basic Auth. Do I have to add anything so that it gets executed for basic auth ?

Comment: Be careful not to get bitten by http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPSPRINGSECURITYCORE-210 as well...

Answer (score -2):

Change

```
grails.plugins.**
```

to

```
grails.plugin.**
```

without the "s" on `grails 2.3.9`.